# Error message while sending email

Tags: apex, trigger, method

I am trying to send some welcoming message to new a contact whenever I create. Where I wrote a class which contain email, sender display name and etc. I want to send email using trigger where the trigger contain method in class. But I am getting the following error message. I know why i am getting error. Even I tried a lot to quit form the error. I am unable to retrieve it. Could anyone please provide solution it.
Here is the class which I created.

```
public  class EmailExample {

    public static void mailSending(){
        Contact con= new Contact();
        Contact con1=[select Email from contact where id=:con.Id];
        String mail1=con1.email;
        String[] mail2= new String[]{mail1};  
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email= new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toadd= new String[]{'mail'}; 
        email.setToAddresses(mail2);
        email.setSubject('Test mail');
        email.setSenderDisplayName('KS Kumar');
        email.setPlainTextBody('This is a sample email');
        Messaging.Email[] mail3 = new Messaging.Email[]{email};
        Messaging.sendEmail(mail3);
    }
}
```

Here it is the trigger:

```
trigger MailingContactTrigger on Contact (after insert) {
    EmailExample.mailSending();

}
```

Error which i faced:

> Apex trigger MailingContactTrigger caused an unexpected exception,
>   contact your administrator: MailingContactTrigger: execution of
>   AfterInsert caused by: System.QueryException: List has no rows for
>   assignment to SObject: Class.EmailExample.mailSending: line 5, column
>   1

Thanking you
KS Kumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking into your question looks like if a contact is inserted you want to sent an email to that contact.

SO you need to pass trigger.New from Trigger to your handler class

like below

```
trigger MailingContactTrigger on Contact (after insert) {
    EmailExample.mailSending(Trigger.New);

}
```

Handler code

```
public  class EmailExample {

    public static void mailSending(List<Contact> lstNewContact)
    {
        Contact con1=[select Email from contact where id IN: lstNewContact LIMIT 1];
        String mail1 = con1.email;
        String[] mail2= new String[]{mail1};  
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email= new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toadd= new String[]{'mail'}; 
        email.setToAddresses(mail2);
        email.setSubject('Test mail');
        email.setSenderDisplayName('KS Kumar');
        email.setPlainTextBody('This is a sample email');
        Messaging.Email[] mail3 = new Messaging.Email[]{email};
        Messaging.sendEmail(mail3);
    }
}
```

Just for a side note this code will not work for bulk record. This will work only for single record.

### Bulkify code

```
public  class EmailExample {

    public static void mailSending(List<Contact> lstNewContact)
    {
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>  mail3 = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        for(Contact objContact: lstNewContact)
        {
            String mail1 = objContact.email;
            String[] mail2= new String[]{mail1};
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email= new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            String[] toadd= new String[]{'mail'}; 
            email.setToAddresses(mail2);
            email.setSubject('Test mail');
            email.setSenderDisplayName('KS Kumar');
            email.setPlainTextBody('This is a sample email');
            mail3.add(email);
        }
        Messaging.sendEmail(mail3);        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ratan, I tried this and finally i got my required one. You are helping me a lot. Hope it will continue in future also.

Comment: @KSKumar you are welcome. We are always here to help everyone also getting knowledge from others :-)